# Where can I find criminal data with basic info?

Tags: data-request, crime

Where can I find a database that compiles US/world criminal data with basic description of the crime? (Preferably with keyword search function)
For example, something like:

Crime: homicide
Year: 20xx
Country/state: xxx
Criminal: husband
Victim: wife
How crime happened: criminal shot victim

Comment: Are you looking only for US/worldwide data? The City of Houston has been publishing fairly detailed crime data since 2009: http://www.houstontx.gov/police/cs/stats2.htm (I'm quite sure that there is another source that includes e.g. location data as Houston/Crime has been used for some time as the preferred example dataset for the presentation of the `R` package `ggmap`).

Answer (score 3):

nibrs has department-reported events

http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/national%20incident-based%20reporting%20system%20%28nibrs%29

ncvs is a complex sample survey

http://www.bjs.gov/index.cfm?ty=dcdetail&iid=245

Answer (score 2):

Besides NIBRS, there are many other open source data form provide county wide statistics, e.g., http://www.city-data.com/crime/crime-Durham-North-Carolina.html

Many cities also provide their crime statistics with frequent updates. For example, Durham Police Department provide interactive maps: http://gisweb.durhamnc.gov/gis_apps/crimedata/dsp_entryform.cfm

Answer (score 2):

I have not seen one worldwide comprehensive source. Instead, I think you will need to find it per country. Typically, this information will be published by the country's National Judicial System or National Statistics Dept. The US Department of State does publish 'summary' statistics on other countries. Here is the home page for crime and safety reports per country:

https://www.osac.gov/pages/ContentReports.aspx?cid=2

Here are some sample links of home pages for crime statistics from the corresponding country:

USA: Federal Bureau of Investigations (FBI):
https://www.fbi.gov/about-us/cjis/ucr/ucr

Canada: National Statistics Department
http://www.statcan.gc.ca/tables-tableaux/sum-som/l01/cst01/legal50a-eng.htm

UK: Office for National Statistics:
http://www.ons.gov.uk/ons/taxonomy/index.html?nscl=Crime+and+Justice

Australia: Australian Institute of Criminology:
http://www.aic.gov.au/statistics/violent%20crime.html

Germany: Bundeskriminalamt ( Federal Criminal Police Office )
http://www.bka.de/nn_256982/EN/Publications/PoliceCrimeStatistics/policeCrimeStatistics__node.html?__nnn=true

The World Bank also has some 'coarse' statistics per country relating to crime. The link below is an example (# of homicides per 100K people):
http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/VC.IHR.PSRC.P5